# i2cdetect not seeing arduino

Tags: arduino, raspbian, iot, i2c

I'm trying to communicate between a raspberry (master) and arduino (slave) via i2c. I've followed this guide http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/ and I've installed and checked all the tools on the raspberry. 
- i2c and spi are enabled
- the raspi has been rebooted
- blacklist and modules have been edited and the lines about i2c have been un-commented

Everything looks fine, but when I run i2cdetect -y 1 I can't see anything connected to the raspberry (The raspberry is a new one so it's 1 and not 0). Are there some other commands to run to check what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I answered this yesterday but it seems to have disappeared. So a short version, you need to set up the arduino as a slave. You need at least this :-

```
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x04
Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
```

Comment: thank you Mike, I did that. In the end I found out the problem were the cables. I changed them and ieverything worked just fine :)